# rewriting urls for static js and css files using nginx server

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

i would like to rewrite js and css files using nginx

i have this urls pattern

css :
`http://myhost.com/css/min/css_home.1330004285.css`

js :
`http://myhost.com/js/min/js_home.1330004285.js`

for the css files have to redirect to
`http://myhost.com/css/min/css_home.css` and the same way for the js files

i tried to resolve this by using thi solution but i doesn't work , it showing me an error when restarting nginx server

```
location ~* \.(css|js) {
 rewrite /(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js) $1.$2 last;
}
```

Comment: -@NoOneElse did you ever find a solution for this? It looks like you are trying to do what I and others have done with Apache using Nginx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files

Answer (score 4):

The rewrite rule seems a bit over complicated.

You can try this:

```
rewrite /(.+/)\.+\.(css|js)$ /$1.$2 last;
```

If you have to use your original one, you need to wrap it in quotes because it includes curly braces ... '{' and '}'

```
rewrite "/(.+)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$" /$1.$2 last;
```