# Nginx: How to redirect JS/CSS http link to other domain?

Tags: nginx

I have few HTTP links to the js/css files. I wanted to redirect it to other location. Example provided below:

Redirection from:

https://ex.example.com/js/file1.js

https://ex.example.com/css/file2.css

https://ex.example.com/css/folder1/file3.css

Redirection to:

https://ex2.example.com/js/file1.js

https://ex2.example.com/css/file2.css

https://ex2.example.com/css/folder1/file3.css

I have tried below settings in nginx.conf. But its not working.

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name ex.example.com;

    location / {
       return 301 https://ex2.example.com;
    }
    location ~* \.(css)$ {
        root https://ex2.example.com/css;
    }
    location ~* \.(js)$ {
        root https://ex2.example.com/js;
    }
    #location /css/ {
    #   return 301 https://ex2.example.com/css;
    #}
    #location /js/ {
    #   return 301 https://ex2.example.com/js;
    #}

    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/myserver.key;
    client_max_body_size 5M;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  }
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: You may be able to use a simple `return 301 https://ex2.example.com$request_uri;` instead of all of your location blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name ex.example.com;

    location / {
       return 301 https://ex2.example.com/$request_uri;
    }

    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/myserver.key;
    client_max_body_size 5M;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  }
}
```

`/$request_uri` will automatically takeup the previous request uri and will add it to the redirection uri. You don't need to match regex and do seperate redirections.

Answer (score 0):

As link below

[rewriting urls for static js and css files using nginx server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423138/rewriting-urls-for-static-js-and-css-files-using-nginx-server)

If you want to redirect only js and css files use this :

```
rewrite /(.*)\.(css|js)(.*)$ https://ex2.example.com/$1.$2$3 last;
```